# C# - Lambda expression for selecting records based on current date?

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a database table called `Event`, which has a `StartDate` column which stores the date the event was recorded. Therefore, I have a `Lambda Expression` where I want to select only those records which has the `StartDate` greater than the current date?

```
public List<Event> GetAllEvents(int Id)
{
      DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Today;
      var events = _context.Event
            .Where(s => s.Id == Id)
             .Select(s => s.StartDate >= currentDateTime)
            .ToList();

     return events;
 }
```

I have tried the above code but its giving me an error:

> Cannot Implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'
>   to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

How can I select all the records that has the StartDate greater than todays date?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Select` is not for filtering. It's for projection. `Where` is how you filter the data:

```
DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Today;
var events = _context.Event
      .Where(s => s.Id == Id && s.StartDate >= currentDateTime)
      .ToList();
```

But, are you sure you only want an event with a given `Id`? I'd expect IDs to be unique, so only one Event should match the `Id`. I think you should skip that condition.

```
DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Today;
var events = _context.Event
      .Where(s => s.StartDate >= currentDateTime)
      .ToList();
```

But I might be wrong, so you should check what `Id` means in your domain and if it makes sense to filter by `StartDate` after you selected Events by `Id`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I wanted to simplify the code that's why i guess I wrote it by mistake